# How to check if a given column is a primary key or an index in sqlite3?

Tags: sql, python-3.x, sqlite

I know that `PRAGMA table_info('table_name');` will describe my table and if the column `pk` is 1 then that column is the primary key of my table. 
Similarly, if I write `PRAGMA index_list('table_name');` it will give me the name of the indexes on the table. 
How do I check if a given column is a primary key of the table? Also I want to check if given an index_name, this index_name is an index of the table.

Edit: 
How can I do this in python?

Comment: I may be misreading, but haven't you answered your own question? "How do I check if a given column is a primary key of the table?" -> "...if the column pk is 1 then that column is the primary key of my table"

Comment: @IMSoP I have updated the question. I want to know how can I do this in python?

Answer (score 0):

if you can read the data into pandas you can do:

```
# read to pandas
df = pd.read_sql("SELECT A, B FROM ...")

# test whether A and B are primary keys
df.set_index(['A','B']).index.is_unique
```